# OleDbDataAdapter .Fill() method gives an exception saying No value given for one or more required parameters

Tags: c#, oledbdataadapter

```
       `OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
        connect.Open();
        string lastName = tBoxSurname.Text;
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM Players WHERE LastName=" + lastName, connect);

        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataset, "Players");

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset;
        dataGridView1.DataMember = "Players";
        connect.Close();`
```

I do not understand why it keeps giving that problem. I looked for different solutions and tried a lot of them but I keep getting the same problem. If someone could please explain what is happening because I have recently started learning about databases.

Comment: !! SQL Injection Alert !! Please read this: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Players WHERE LastName = ?", connect);

command.Parameters.Add("LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = tBoxSurname.Text;

adapter.SelectCommand = command;
```

Please post your code next time as a snippet and not as a picture! :)

Comment: It just keeps on returning an empty data table

Comment: @augustovandyk, remove the quotes around the command parameter for "tBoxSurname.Text".  You want the value of whatever entered for the query to execute, not the literal "tBoxSurname.Text".  You wont have anyone with that actual last name :)

Comment: I don't understand which tBoxSurname.Text has quotes around it. Thanks for all the replies though.

Comment: Yeah you are right, of course without quotes. Sry for that careless mistake :)